# Dynamically fill QTreeView so that app doesn't crash

Tags: python, pyqt, treeview, pyqt5, qtreewidget

I want to show a tree view of how nodes in an OPC server are organized. I'm using `PyQt5` and `opcua` to achieve this. To try the code, I used [Prosys OPC UA Simulation Server](https://www.prosysopc.com/products/opc-ua-simulation-server/), and it works fine. It looks like this:

[image]

However, when I tried to use the code with [real publicly available servers](http://www.opclabs.com/resources/product-information/articles/1094-public-demo-opc-xml-da-server-2), the app crashes. I believe this is happening because in real servers the amount of existing nodes is huge, and the app has a lot to process then.

So I was wondering if there is a way to fill the tree 'on-demand'. Namely, look up the children nodes only when the user clicks on a node, so that only nodes that should be on screen are present as items in the `QTreeWidget` object. I don't know if this is possible, as currently I'm filling the tree completely in one go, not just when the user demands to see some node's children.

This is my current code:

```
import sys
from opcua import Client
from PyQt5 import QtWidgets, QtGui

class Window(QtWidgets.QWidget):
    def __init__(self, parent=None):
        super(Window, self).__init__(parent)        
        self.node_tree = QtWidgets.QTreeWidget()
        layout = QtWidgets.QVBoxLayout()
        layout.addWidget(self.node_tree)
        self.setLayout(layout)

        self.client = Client('opc.tcp://127.0.0.1:53530/UA/Sim')
        self.client.connect()
        self.root = self.client.get_root_node()
        self.fill_tree(self.node_tree, self.root)

    def fill_tree(self, group, node):
        item = QtWidgets.QTreeWidgetItem(group, [str(node)])
        children = node.get_children()
        variables = node.get_variables()
        for child in children:
            if child in variables:
                QtWidgets.QTreeWidgetItem(item, [str(child) + ' (variable)'])
            else:
                self.fill_tree(item, child)

    def closeEvent(self,event):
        self.client.disconnect()
        sys.exit(0)

if __name__ == '__main__':
    app = QtWidgets.QApplication(sys.argv)
    ex = Window()
    ex.show()
    sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

Comment: I do not know anything about OPC, but I think I can help you, it seems to me that only child nodes that are not variables can have children, am I right?

Comment: @eyllanesc I'm not sure I understood what you meant. Basically: 1) Variables can't have children. 2) Any other node (that is, any node that is not a variable) may or may not have children.

Comment: Okay, I understand you. Conceptually, the model should be similar to QFileSystemModel.

Comment: @eyllanesc Yes, it's pretty much the same now that you mention it: files would be variables, and folders would be nodes.

Comment: Why did you add: `self.client.disconnect()`? Can you get nodes after being disconnected?

Comment: @eyllanesc No, you can't. But notice that in the previous line I call the recursive function `self.fill_tree()`, so when the client is disconnected all information has already been gathered. I added it because I wanted to emphasize that the client should disconnect before closing the application (either deliberately or if some exception occurred), that's all.

Comment: @eyllanesc I ended up finding the solution, but I don't think it will help other people as it is way too specific IMHO, so I think that deleting the question would be the best decision, wouldn't it?

Comment: always published the solution, for example could from there find a better solution, I for example was moving in a solution but for lack of time I still do not finish it. Your question seems interesting to me since the correct solution must be implemented on-demand and for this you must use fetchMore() and canFetchMore()

Comment: @eyllanesc I'll post it in some minutes, but I haven't used those functions you mention, so maybe you can improve my solution which I believe is far from being the best one (it's rather inefficient). There are two or three tricks regarding OPC wich you might not know, so I'll put those in my answer too so you can take them into account!

Comment: for me the main problem is the cost of getting children from a node, maybe your solution can help me improve the time.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I managed to find a solution that works, but I think it's far from being the best one. This is the code:

```
import sys
from opcua import Client
from PyQt5 import QtWidgets, QtGui

class Window(QtWidgets.QWidget):
    def __init__(self, parent=None):
        super(Window, self).__init__(parent)        
        self.node_tree = QtWidgets.QTreeWidget()
        layout = QtWidgets.QVBoxLayout()
        layout.addWidget(self.node_tree)
        self.setLayout(layout)

        self.client = Client('opc.tcp://opcuaserver.com:48010')
        self.client.connect()
        self.root = self.client.get_root_node()
        self.add_node_to_tree(self.node_tree, self.root)
        self.node_tree.itemExpanded.connect(self.get_node_from_tree_item)

    def get_node_from_tree_item(self, item):
        ## Get the NodeId as a string
        aux = item.text(0)
        start = aux.find('NodeId(') + len('NodeId(')
        end = aux.find(')')
        node_str = str(aux[start:end])
        ## If the ID is defined as an 'i=', then what comes after the ';'
        ## should be ignored to access the node
        if (node_str[:2] == 'i=') & (node_str.find(';') != -1):
            new_end = node_str.find(';')
            node_str = node_str[:new_end]
        node = self.client.get_node(node_str)
        children = node.get_children()
        variables = node.get_variables()
        item.takeChildren()
        for child in children:
            if child in variables:
                self.add_node_to_tree(item, child, True)
            else:
                self.add_node_to_tree(item, child, False)

    def add_node_to_tree(self, group, node, var=False):
        item = QtWidgets.QTreeWidgetItem(group, [str(node) + var*' (variable)'])
        children = node.get_children()
        for child in children:
                QtWidgets.QTreeWidgetItem(item, [str(child)])

    def closeEvent(self,event):
        self.client.disconnect()
        sys.exit(0)

if __name__ == '__main__':
    app = QtWidgets.QApplication(sys.argv)
    ex = Window()
    ex.show()
    sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

The comments regarding nodes' IDs are not relevant regarding the tree in PyQt, they are just formatting issues related to `opcua` library.

What I think can (and should) be improved is the fact that every time an item is expanded, all its children are removed with `item.takeChildren()` to add them back later when calling `add_node_to_tree()` method. I know this isn't right, but I couldn't find another way to do it.